# Plot a plane and points in 3D simultaneously

Tags: python, matplotlib, plane, matplotlib-3d

I m trying to plot simultaneously a plane and some points in 3D with Matplotlib.
I have no errors just the point will not appear.
I can plot at different times some points and planes but never at same time.
The part of the code looks like :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

point  = np.array([1, 2, 3])
normal = np.array([1, 1, 2])

point2 = np.array([10, 50, 50])

# a plane is a*x+b*y+c*z+d=0
# [a,b,c] is the normal. Thus, we have to calculate
# d and we're set
d = -point.dot(normal)

# create x,y
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(10), range(10))

# calculate corresponding z
z = (-normal[0] * xx - normal[1] * yy - d) * 1. /normal[2]

# plot the surface
plt3d = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
plt3d.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, alpha=0.2)


#and i would like to plot this point : 
ax.scatter(point2[0] , point2[1] , point2[2],  color='green')

plt.show()
```

Comment: @AndreyRubshtein how is that related? The question your link to is about `matlab`, this is about `matplotlib`

Comment: Hey @tom, it has an explanation about the math formula, the one that is called 'Calculate corresponding z' in the original question

Comment: Ok sure, although that's not really what this question and answers are about

Comment: Just to mention it: this method will fail for normal vectors which have a z-component equal to zero! So, for example, `normal = np.array([1,0,0])` will throw `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide` and no plane is drawn!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will need to tell the axes that you want new plots to *add* to the current plots on the axes rather than overwriting them. To do this, you will need to use [`axes.hold(True)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hold)

```
# plot the surface
plt3d = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
plt3d.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, alpha=0.2)

# Ensure that the next plot doesn't overwrite the first plot
ax = plt.gca()
ax.hold(True)

ax.scatter(points2[0], point2[1], point2[2], color='green')
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

As [@tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell) pointed out in the comments, they are considering discontinuing support for `hold`. As a result, a better approach may be to use the axes directly to add more plots as in [@tom's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061408/670206)

Comment: Do you actually use `hold` day-to-day?  We have been talking about deprecating it and I would like to talk to someone who actually uses it....

Comment: @tcaswell I do tend to, but I think it's mainly due to the habits I developed from using MATLAB. That being said, I actually do like the alternate approach mentioned by [tom](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36061408/670206) but I never think to use it!

Comment: Also, I think most things default to `hold==True`.  If you find a use case where you _can not_ just remove it please make an issue on GH

Comment: AttributeError: 'Axes3D' object has no attribute 'hold'

Answer (score 28):

Just to add to @suever's answer, you there's no reason why you can't create the `Axes` and then plot both the surface and the scatter points on it. Then there's no need to use `ax.hold()`:

```
# Create the figure
fig = plt.figure()

# Add an axes
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

# plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, alpha=0.2)

# and plot the point 
ax.scatter(point2[0] , point2[1] , point2[2],  color='green')
```

Answer (score 12):

Just elaborating a little more on the math part (and how it works), may be useful for someone, the equation of a plane with unit normal vector **n** containing a point **a** is shown as follows:

[image]

so that the equation of the plane here is x + y + 2*z = 9 and the following code can simply be used to plot the given plane:

```
# create the figure
fig = plt.figure()

# add axes
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(10), range(10))
z = (9 - xx - yy) / 2 

# plot the plane
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Plotting the point is straightforward with `scatter()`